# How to stop a service from a script called by a cron job?

Tags: ruby

I have a cron job that runs every X minutes and is supposed to restart the `amazon-ssm-agent` service. However, I noticed that my ruby script actually never does this.

Here's what my crontab looks like:

```
* * * * * /root/./my_script.rb
```

Here's the very plain contents of the ruby script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
#

command = "service amazon-ssm-agent stop"
system(command)
```

If I'm monitoring `/var/log/amazon/ssm/amazon-ssm-agent.log`, it never stops. If I check the service with `service amazon-ssm-agent status`, it still shows online.

What's the best way to stop or restart a service from within a ruby script that's called by Cron job? I have been facing a pretty major issue today and I think this is the reason why.

I have tried to capture the result and write it to a file, but when the cron job runs, the file is created but it's empty. Here's what the ruby script looks like now:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

command = "service amazon-ssm-agent stop"
result = system(command)
File.open("/root/result.txt", "w") {|f| f.write(result)}
```

I have also tried to just modify the script to this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

command = "service amazon-ssm-agent stop"
```

but still no luck. I have even just modified my cron job itself to start the service rather than calling the ruby script that starts the service, but no luck:

```
* * * * * service amazon-ssm-agent start
```

The service never gets started.

Comment: Does it work if you replace the Ruby script with a shell script?

Comment: I haven't tried it just yet but I'm basically trying to incorporate this into a relatively large Ruby script.

Comment: How do you know if the Ruby script even runs? If this script is run as root, you have to make sure Ruby is in the `PATH` of root. I suggest a simple test like `system("date > /tmp/ruby-test.out")` to check if it even runs.

Comment: @Casper there are other pieces of code in the Ruby script that runs before and after this line. It's almost like everything works except for trying to start a service within the Ruby script which is called from the cron job.

Comment: What’s the result of the `system` call, i.e. its return value?

Comment: Can't you use `\`#{command}\`` ?

Comment: When I capture the result and write it out to a file, the file is empty. When I tried to use `#{command}`, it still didn't work even though the sample file was created. It's very strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the issue, which was silly. I realized that the service command doesn't reside in the environment paths that the cron job has, so that's why it never worked. Neither is `ifconfig`, which is what I was trying to for testing.

So I had to replace my `service` command in the Ruby script with `/usr/sbin/service` and it worked flawlessly afterwards.